# How do I apply a macro to an entire column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that, when run it separates values into different cells within the row. The delimiter is two spaces or more. This is an example, all of this is in one cell.

```
One Space    Two  Spaces    Three   Spaces
```

Will become:

```
One Space Two Spaces Three Space
```

With each word being in its own cell.

I have one whole column with about 300,000 rows with data similar to that, I would like how know how can I apply the following macro to the entire column.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim txt As String
Dim FullName() As String
Dim i As Long, colOffset As Long

Set rng = ActiveCell
txt = rng.Value2

FullName = Split(txt, String(2, " "))

For i = LBound(FullName) To UBound(FullName)
    If Not WorksheetFunction.Trim(FullName(i)) = vbNullString Then
        Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Trim(FullName(i))
        colOffset = colOffset + 1
        rng.Offset(0, colOffset).Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Trim(FullName(i))
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: To some extent it seems like you are recreating the "text-to-columns" functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This will split the ***selected*** cells by spaces, into the columns to the right.

```
For Each c In Selection.Cells
    cellvalues = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(c.Value), " ")
    c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(cellvalues)).Value = cellvalues
Next
```

Just remove the `Offset(0,1).` part to overwrite the values. Instead of `Selection`, you could use a dynamic range or one identified by code.